# fast fourier transformation on images -- python

Tags: python, computer-vision, image

I did Fast Fourier Transform on lena image and I would like to extract real and imaginary parts of its spectrum.

This is my code:

```
f1 = np.fft.fft2(image1)
fft1 = np.fft.fftshift(f1)
plt.plot(fft1.real,fft1.imag,'r.')
plt.show()
```

The imaginary part is zero on the plot, but when I use `fft1.imag` it has values like these:

```
array([[    0.        , -1673.72316163,   116.13415499, ...,
          791.3382541 ,  -116.13415499,  1673.72316163],
       [ -978.43189197,   257.24363428,   282.28889913, ...,
         -247.13630325,  -399.86302292,  1203.02050023],
       [  955.82577247,   563.49671551, -1091.82214096, ...,
          831.28592384,  -249.0599705 ,  -349.12835212],
       ...,
       [ -218.831779  , -1249.05657617,  -891.12913564, ...,
          473.98187095,  -335.69043503,  -247.79973671],
       [ -955.82577247,   349.12835212,   249.0599705 , ...,
         -244.99119848,  1091.82214096,  -563.49671551],
       [  978.43189197, -1203.02050023,   399.86302292, ...,
           55.02243211,  -282.28889913,  -257.24363428]])
```

How can I get the real and imaginary parts of the spectrum?